# Search field and box in Nav bar using zurb has black background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zurb-foundation, frontend

I ran into a weird bug with my ruby on rails app where I want to display the search field and button in the navbar but the view looks like this image

[image: this]

The problem is that it has black in the background for just the search box and button.

The following code is below:

```
<section class="top-bar-section">

  <ul class="left">

    <%= form_tag('/search') do %>

      <li>

        <%= text_field_tag :query, nil ,:placeholder => "Search for designs", :id=>"nav_search_box" %>

      </li>

      <li>

        <%= submit_tag 'Search', :class=>"round button", :id=>"nav_search_btn" %>

      </li>

    <% end %>

  </ul>

</section>
```

Any insight on fixing this bug would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in the official docs, under other elements.

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/top-bar.html

"can use a small Foundation button in the nav, just include has-form as a class for its parent li."